# the use of Thread.yield(); java

Tags: java, yield

Can anyone explain this code:

```
public class Main implements Runnable{

private int i;
public synchronized void run() {
    System.out.print("i = "+ i +"\n");
    if (i % 5 != 0) {
        i++;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++, i++) {
        if (x > 1) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main n = new Main();
    for (int x = 100; x > 0; --x) {
        new Thread(n).start();
    }
}
}
```

and how the output is

```
i= 0
i= 5
i= 10
i= 15
i= 20
.
.
.
i= 499
```

Comment: The question is very open-ended. What do you not understand? Where are you stuck trying to understand it? Why does thread.yield throw you off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom loop creates 100 threads. Each thread is run immediately, in parallel with the others. In each thread,

- at the start, the current value of shared-attribute 'i' is printed
- if i is not divisible by 5, it is incremented once
- then a loop is executed, up to 5 times. The last 3 times it is executed, it yields to other threads. Every time this loop executes, it increments shared-variable 'i'

Therefore, i is incremented 5 times if it was divisible by 5, and 6 times if it was not. But, the run() method is **synchronized**. *Therefore, no other thread is allowed to execute while one of them is already executing*: your program is effectively single-threaded, yield()s are ignored (no other thread can execute), and the output identical to

```
for (int i=0; i<500; i+= 5) System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(499);
```

Remove the synchronized to see all sorts of race-conditions altering the output.

Answer (score 2):

Main thread creates 100 threads and each thread executes a synchronized method so that they serialize their execution. Every thread prints the current value of i(which is 0 by default at the beginning) and increments it 5 times such that the next thread to take cpu(and execute the body) prints the new value of `i`.

`Thread.yield();` 
 relinquishes the CPU but it does not mean that it releases the lock. That is why each thread executes `run` method after the previous thread has finished and not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that [`yield` does not release the monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3). So all your threads run sequentially, i.e. `yield` does not allow other threads to run because it is within a `synchronized` block and the monitor remains locked.

Comment: @assylias can't tell why no upvotes here - this is a crucial addition IMO